# How to contribute to Linux kernel development? Use the latest source code?

Tags: linux

I like Linux and am interested in its kernel development. But I have some puzzles about the process. The biggest puzzle is that do I need to download the latest kernel source code (e.g. the linux-next tree or staging tree) and make it run on my target machine?

My concern is that if doing so, it is very possible to make my target machine dead due to the immature code. And it is not so easy to do so, right?

But if not doing so, how could I find bugs of the latest source code? Or how to further develop it?

My target machine is ARM based, e.g. BeagleBoard or phone.

Thanks!

BR

Comment: Your question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/4576332/841108 ; you certainly should read several books and be able to compile easily a kernel (so knowing the usual tools like git is a must ...)

Answer (score 5):

Why dont you have a look at this website (and their mailing list)

http://kernelnewbies.org/

Comment: Thank you! I know that website but didn't involve myself in it. I will try it more.

Answer (score 4):

Working from the latest version is a good idea, but you don't have to go bleeding edge by any means. As long as you're on a relatively recent version, whoever the maintainer is of the subsystem(s) you're patching should be able to integrate your patch fairly easily.

Just don't start by rewriting a subsystem from scratch, or writing a new one from the ground up - it'll get rejected outright. Start small and build your rep, then start increasing the scope of your work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! So no need to use the latest version. But when I have some new patch, I think I need to check the latest version to see whether it is already fixed, right?

Comment: Yes, and to make the maintainer's life easier, check that it applies cleanly (or at least as clean as possible) to the latest stuff.